# Add to cart button with jquery

Tags: php, ajax

I have a working add to cart format with php jquery but i tried some other method which doesnt add, i want to know the reason for that...

The first code below works perfectly using jquery and php...

```
<?php foreach ($photos as $photo): ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
     <a href="order_review.php?id=<?php echo $photo->id; ?>"><img  src="<?php echo $photo->image_path(); 
     ?>" class="img-thumbnail" alt="<?php echo $photo->title; ?>"></a>
    <div class="caption">
    <h3 class="text-info text-center"><?php echo $photo->title; ?></h3>
    <p class="text-danger text-center price"><s>N</s><?php echo $photo->price; ?></p>
    <div class=" mx-auto">
    <select name="quantity" class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="quantity<?php echo $photo->id; ?>">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $photo->id; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_title" id="title<?php echo $photo->id; ?>" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $photo->title; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price<?php echo $photo->id; ?>" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $photo->price; ?>"/>
      </div>
      <div class="mx-auto">
      <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" id="<?php echo $photo->id; ?>" class="add_to_cart btn-sm btn btn-outline-secondary" value="Add to cart" />
      </div>
     </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I am using jquery with an html id element to load the second code into same page but the add to cart button doesn't respond... that is the problem...

Also in the second code, i added a jquery slider to the script, that is the purpose for the if($total_row > 0)

```
if($total_row > 0){
        $output .= '
         <div class="row">
        ';
      foreach($photos as $photo){ 
          $output .= '
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
     <a href="order_review.php?id='.$photo->id.'"><img  src="'.$photo->image_path().'" class="img-thumbnail" alt="'.$photo->title.'"></a>
    <div class="caption">
    <h3 class="text-info text-center">'.$photo->title.'</h3>
    <p class="text-danger text-center price"><s>N</s>'.$photo->price.'</p>
    <div class=" mx-auto">
    <select name="quantity" class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="quantity'.$photo->id.'">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" value="'.$photo->id.'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_title" id="title'.$photo->id.'" class="form-control" value="'.$photo->title.'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price'.$photo->id.'" class="form-control" value="'.$photo->price.'"/>
      </div>
      <div class="mx-auto">
      <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" id="'.$photo->id.'" class="add_to_cart btn-sm btn btn-outline-secondary" value="Add to cart" />
      </div>
     </div>
          ';
      }
    }else{
        $output .= '
        </div>
         <h3 align="center">No product found</h3>
        ';
    }
echo $output;
```

What is the difference and please someone explain why it is not adding... i hope i have asked this question well enough.

This is the jquery

```
$('.add_to_cart').click(function(){
    var product_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var product_title = $('#title'+product_id).val();   
    var product_price = $('#price'+product_id).val();
    var product_quantity = $('#quantity'+product_id).val(); 
    var action = "add";
    if(product_quantity > 0){
        $.ajax({
            url:"aon.php",
            method:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{
                product_id:product_id,
                product_title:product_title,
                product_price:product_price,
                product_quantity:product_quantity,
                action:action
            },
            success:function(data){
                $('#order_table').html(data.order_table);
                $('.badge').text(data.cart_item);
                alert("Product has been added to cart");
            }
        });
    }else{
      alert("Please enter number of quantity"); 
    }   
    });
```

Comment: Can you show the jQuery script for the add to cart feature?

Comment: @KoalaYeung i just posted the jquery